# How to obtain errors in Yii

Tags: php, logging, yii

I've got Yii-based site, the system I don't know originally and it came to me from other man and there's "Error 500 Trying to get property of non-object"

I read a ton of literature regarding logging errors in Yii, but nothing seems to work for me. Here's what I have in main.php for logging:

```
'log' => array(
    'class' => 'CLogRouter',
    'routes' => array(
        array(
            'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
            'enabled' => true,
            'categories' => 'system.*',
            'levels'=>'error, warning, trace, profile, info',
            'showInFireBug' => true
        ),
    ),
),
```

the thing is, the domain hosting error log doesn't have errors in it (while it has all the time for other sites, having troubles).
I tried enabling php errors through .htaccess, I tried doing it in main.php - nothing works.

Please help - how can I see the errors in more details and finally fix them in Yii?..

Comment: please post screen of the error page

Answer (score 0):

Add this on your main.php file to show error logs. Then the Application Log will be  shown below in every page.

```
'log' => array(
 'class' => 'CLogRouter',
 'routes' => array(
    array(
        'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
        'levels' => 'trace, info, error, warning, 
  vardump',
     ),
    // uncomment the following to show log 
 messages on web pages
    array(
        'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
        'enabled' => YII_DEBUG,
        'levels' => 'error, warning, trace, notice',
        'categories' => 'application',
        'showInFireBug' => false,
      ),
   ),
),
```

Edit:

Here you have to consider that Yii writes logs after the main script is ended, So if you terminate your script using die() command, you never let Yii write it down. To avoid such problems you should terminate the script using Yii::app()->end() command.

See More:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#message-routing

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help :(

Comment: Can you make a try after changing the categories to 'categories'=>'system.db.*', On CWebLogRoute class

Comment: sorry, doesn't help too :(

Comment: I feel like I will have to look through all the code to find out whether we have 'die' there after the person did the site..